# DAL Design - approach for strongly typed "summary" lists

Tags: .net, data-access-layer

I am currently re-developing our LOB VB.NET application to be structured using a proper n-tier architecture (I'm the sole developer).  Also moving to strongly-typed lists from custom class rather than un-typed datasets.  I have settled on approaching this using custom DTOs rather than Entity Framework or typed datasets based on what I have read.  I am new to this and my question is a simple one but couldn't find any direct answer on other posts.

I have a Customer class, with 20 fields/properties containing various data.  This is required for editing a single record.  I also need to return a list of all customers for a summary grid, containing just 5 of these fields.  I assume I wouldn't use List(Of Customer) and simply not bind the 15 unrequired fields in the UI as that would be very inefficient?  Should I be creating a separate DTO so I could use List(Of CustomerSummary)?  Let's assume in the UI I also have 5 other grids showing different field sets - do I have to create a class for each of these?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Creating separate DataTable will make it less maintainable. Especially when you need to modify a field. Just create one DataTable from the customer table. Then create DataView for each grid you need to be displayed. By using DataView, you can manipulate the data via DataGrid (e.g. sort, filter, etc).

If you really concern about the fetching performance, just create Command in the TableAdapter for each grid you need to be displayed. Customize the SQL command to ensure you fetch only required fields.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  To be honest though that's pretty much how I've done it previously, but looking to move to a strongly typed model rather than using datasets and views, unless I need the additional dataset functionality such as hierarchy for multi-level grids.